# Android TextView casting error: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-inflate

I have the following textview in a layout file, this is the full contents of the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/seasonTitle"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:maxHeight="26sp"
    android:background="#FFCC3333"
     />
```

It has been in my app for a year or so with no problems. All of the sudden I'm getting the error: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

I can't figure it out.

The layout file is inflated with code like this:

```
TextView seasonTv = (TextView)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.section_title, null);
```

Any insight on why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are passing in null as the root element of the view group. I would assume that the inflater is defaulting your view group to a linear layout, when you don't actually have a view group at all. I would try to modify your inflate call, as your layout file appears OK.

source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: Your answer solved the immediate problem, thank you!, but it puzzles me. Please help me understand this better. This code has been working for the better part of a year. The same basic line of code 10 lines above it ran fine. Why would the behavior change like that?

Comment: Just a guess, but is the other layout a form of view group, or is it a textview as well? I would say that if its a view group, the linear layout default doesn't hurt anything. Other than that, I'm really not sure as to why the call works for one layout and not another.

Comment: thanks for the follow up. No, it is a call to the same layout file with a cast to TextView. It is 12 lines earlier...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
View season = (View)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.section_title, null);
TextView seasonTv =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seasonTitle);
```

You trying to inflate layout and cast it to TextView widget.
You should inflate layout and find widget

Comment: Are you saying that a view in a layout file must have a ViewGroup/Layout based view as a parent? I had understood that any view was allowed in a layout file.